# Deploying to diffrent cloud services vs using vnet subnets

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I am currently working on a task to deploy a website on a VM and connecting it to a database which is located on another VM 
currently i have both VM set up on one cloud service with different subnets to separate them and am researching which is better keeping it the way it is or perhaps deploying each VM into a separate cloud service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two word, I would suggest you to keep both machines in the same cloud service. Here below is the long version :

Why? An important thing in your architecture is to be able to use the internal IP adress from the machines (of type 192.168 or 10.0) in the communications between your web server and database. Using these private addresses (called Dynamic IP (DIP) in opposition with the Virtual IP (VIP) which is the public address of the cloud service) allow Azure to not have to route your requests over the public internet, so you avoid going through the datacenters load balancers,... You gain in Security and performance.

Actually if you are in the same cloud service, you can use directly the DIP addressing system, so it is much easier to keep your current architecture. There would be other possibility to split them up, but it would only add complexity and bring not that much benefits...

Comment: I think you can find a perfect opinion on what I think in the answer of david here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526717/how-to-connect-2-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure-to-have-two-tier-architecture

Answer (score 0):

Cloud services are meant to group VMs of the same kind, e.g. to load balance across them.  If you deploy the database to the same virtual network (same or different subnet) you will be able to communicate with the database over the private IP space.

Comment: I do agree that it would be possible to deploy two cloud services in the same Vnet. However I strongly disagree that the cloud services are meant to group VM of the same kind, I would say that on an aivalability set.